# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Use $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ when:

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[f(n+1) - f(n)] = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) - f(1)$

to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=1$

What I have tried:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)$$

Therefore;
$$\implies \lim_{n \to \infty}f(n) - f(1) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{n}-\frac{1}{(1+1)^2}$$

Though it does not look to me that this equals to 1, only hints on where do I go from here?

Comment: If $\ f(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\ $, then what you have is $\ \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty( f(n)-f(n+1))\ $, not $\ \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty( f(n+1)-f(n))\ $.

Comment: To make your series match 1., you will need to use $f(n) = -\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n)-f(1)=\frac 1 {n^{2}}-1 \to -1$ so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2} \right) =-\lim [f(n)-1]=1$

Comment: Ah okay, so I do not replace the fraction as $f(n)$ represents that it's a function of a fraction, so not $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right)}{n}$?

Comment: @emilj.limes $f(n)$ is just $\frac 1 {n^{2}}$.